# Parse List<String> from hh:mm format to new List in decimal (hours) format

Tags: c#

I have a List:

```
 List<String> sqlListHrsUptime;
```

that holds a number of strings in "hh:mm" format.

I want to convert to a new List in decimal format. I've found:

```
TimeSpan.Parse("04:03").TotalHours;
```

As a means to do it for individual values.

I can't seem to create a working solution to do it for a list that will have a varying number of strings (it is pulling data from a SQL table that the user enters the parameters). How can I directly copy the first list to a new list while using the Parse().TotalHours method? Or another solution that would accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you only want the `TotalHours` in the list if you can have the full `TimeSpan`?

```
List<TimeSpan> spans = sqlListHrsUptime.Select(s => TimeSpan.Parse(s)).ToList();
```

or shorter with `List.ConvertAll`:

```
List<TimeSpan> spans = sqlListHrsUptime.ConvertAll(TimeSpan.Parse);
```

If you insist on `decimal`:

```
List<decimal> hours = sqlListHrsUptime
    .Select(s => (decimal)TimeSpan.Parse(s).TotalHours)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Am I interpreting this correctly in that it would give me hours with the decimal representing any minutes or seconds? "This property converts the value of this instance from ticks to hours. This number might include whole and fractional hours." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DanGrover: no, the decimals represent also hours, but the remainder/fractional part(f.e. 2 hours and 30 minutes is `2.5` TotalHours). However, i don't know your requirement, you have used `TotalHours` and said that you need decimals.

Comment: Thanks! That was very helpful. I'm thinking decimal so that I can sum the list for another part of my program.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this:

```
var output = new List<decimal>();

foreach (var item in sqlListHrsUptime)
{
    output.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(TimeSpan.Parse(item).TotalHours));
}
```